# How to get overall CPU Usage Percentage in Windows over a period of time

Tags: .net-core

I am trying to capture the average Total CPU usage over a 5 minute time in windows.  My thought was to capture the CPU usage every second and in the end average each value.

Before I can do the above I wanted to make sure I was getting the correct current value so I started with the example from here:
[How to get CPU Usage and Virtual Memory for a process in .Net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54178660/how-to-get-cpu-usage-and-virtual-memory-for-a-process-in-net-core)

And modified it to output the CPU usage each second so I can compare the value it is picking up with what Task Manager shows:

```
            var value = cpuCounter.NextValue();

            // In most cases you need to call .NextValue() twice
            if (Math.Abs(value) <= 0.00)
                value = cpuCounter.NextValue();

            for (int i64 = 0; i64 < 10000; ++i64)
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                value = cpuCounter.NextValue();
                Debug.WriteLine("CPU Counter Value: " + value);
            }
```

My issue with the output of the above code is each output is about 10% lower than Task Manager.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is not much point to it, that performance counter already works like that.  Simply call NextValue() once every 5 minutes instead of once a second.  And my crystal ball says that you're using the wrong one to get it to match Task Manager, use "Processor Information" instead of "Processor".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24840360/17034

Comment: is there an article that describes the behavior of NextValue behaves this way?  It makes sense as you describe just wanted to see something that confirms it since this is such a hard thing to validate and I have not been able to find anything else